# How to play google drive mp3 file using html audio tag?

Tags: cross-browser, google-drive-api, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

My aim is to play the mp3 file from the google drive. I am using the plugin MediaElement js. The reference I got is https://www.portalzine.de/dev/html5/hosting-mp3-files-on-google-drive-html5-audio-player/
This is working in chrome, Mozilla firefox but not in IE-11, safari and opera. I want this to be play in all browsers. Please give me the suggestions....

Comment: Check this out, a better solution https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65763/how-can-i-hotlink-an-mp3-in-google-drive-with-a-url-ending-in-mp3

Comment: Above link also didn't help me, what I did is downloaded the Files from Drive that I wanted to link, than copied it's URL Location and used it for my Audio src, it worked... Not sure if the URL is permanent or it changes with time. Will check that

Answer (score 36):

**1. URL for the audio file (anyone can view)**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-/view?usp=sharing

**2. Extract the id from URL**

```
1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-
```

**3. URL for playing the audio file**

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={id}
```

example:

https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-

**4. URL for downloading the audio file**

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id={id}&export=download
```

example:

https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-&export=download

**5. HTML for playing audio:**

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={id}">
</audio>
```

example:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-">
</audio>
```

**6. HTML for downloading audio:**

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id={id}&export=download"/>Download
```

example:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGyO9S-&export=download"/>Download
```

Comment: great!! that's saved me alot!

Comment: Not working working

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works, whether drive.google.com or docs.google.com (I see both are used here).

Answer (score 11):

In another thread on another page someone wrote the only solution that has worked for me:

If you share an MP3 by link, you obtain a link like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/view?usp=sharing
where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the ID of your MP3 file. Then you can obtain a direct link to this audio by

http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
In particular you can use

```html
<audio controls>
   <source src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" type="audio/mp3">
   <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio :(</p>
</audio>
```

The first link is the one you normally get, the other link is what you want to use with

Try to think of this as HTML code:

```html
<audio controls>    
    <source src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" type="audio/mp3">    
</audio>
```

Make sure you convert that link right and it will work!

Answer (score 7):

I'm using [Direct Link Creator](http://directlink.booogle.net/) plugin of Google Drive and get the link easily. Here's an example.

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_ETxiqrp0SzbF9VQ3JCS2hnSlU">
</audio>

<video controls="controls">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0JMGMGgxp9WMEdWb1hyQUhlOWs" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Comment: Is this working on iPhone? I'm doing same and working on desktop browsers. But not working on iPhone. (Chrome and Safari both)

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to accomplish this inside the SSML audio tag for Actions on Google. None of the above steps seemed to work. I finally found a solution.

1) Get the file ID from the sharing link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/your_file_id/view?usp=sharing

2) Construct the direct link
http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id

3) Paste the direct link into a web browser and hit enter

4) Copy the resulting URL after you have been redirected by your browser
Note: This will be a much longer URL that looks something like this:
https://doc-XX-XX-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/000000000000000/0000000000000000000000/*/your_file_id?e=open

Using this final URL is the only way I could get my uploaded sound files to work with Actions on Google.

Comment: hello, im using this link actually for streaming media files in an app: http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id does it have any daily limits or other restrictions?