# Audio mp3 not playing in HTML

Tags: html, html5-audio

I downloaded a mp3 audio file and uploaded it in Google Drive. I copied the link and pasted it in  src in HTML. I'm getting the controls but the audio is not playing anyhow. What have i done wrong?

Code:

```html
<audio controls loop>  
 <source="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NE1YL45F3gC0PKgIn42WvjIlmtsBavei/view?usp=sharing" type=audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Comment: The URL you have points to an HTML document, not an mp3.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos please read how code should look like  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp). You are missing src, and quotes.

Also this is duplicate question of:
[How to play google drive mp3 file using html audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392072/how-to-play-google-drive-mp3-file-using-html-audio-tag)

```html
<audio controls loop>  
 <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NE1YL45F3gC0PKgIn42WvjIlmtsBavei" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```